# Is it possible to retrieve data from a intermediate node in Tor browser

Tags: tor, sslstrip

I'm using Tor browser for my internet surfing and check my email,
my questions are

1. Is my internet services provider able to see the websites I visited
2. Is it possible to retrieve a login information like username and
   password of my email account from intermediate node between Tor
   browser and web server
3. Is it possible to retrieve email content like mail body and
   attchments from intermediate node

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Is my internet services provider able to see the websites I visited

No. Your Internet service provider can not see which website you visit (I suppose you use Tor correctly without your personal settings/configurations you may have done. Tor will take care of your DNS leaks and so on)

> 2. Is it possible to retrieve a login information like username and password of my email account from intermediate node between Tor
>      browser and web server

First of all, using your credentials to log into this or that website breaks, by time, the anonymity Tor provides you. Also, an attacker may [eavesdrop the exit nodes](http://archive.wired.com/politics/security/news/2007/09/embassy_hacks?currentPage=all) where Tor does not control the traffic.

> 3. Is it possible to retrieve email content like mail body and attachments from intermediate node

Once again, using your credentials through Tor breaks your anonymity. Tor intermediate nodes are too hard theoretically to break (of course, there are *buts*). Real life eavesdropping that targeted Tor users has been done on exit nodes such as when this [Swedish researcher compromised username/passwords](https://lwn.net/Articles/249388/) of lot of Tor users (in which case, of course, your attachments and so on are also compromised)

Comment: when packet arrive to exit node packet still encrypted with SSL?

Comment: @dilee Yes, it is still encrypted. But Tor does not encrypt that packet between the exit nodes and the destination.

Answer (score 1):

In theory no; the point of Tor is each intermediate node (called a [relay node](https://www.eff.org/torchallenge/what-is-tor.html)) has it's own layer of encryption. However the last node before the message reaches it's final destination (called the exit node) will be able to see the unencrypted version of the message. I think [this article](https://hackertarget.com/tor-exit-node-visualization/) states it nicely:

> Tor Exit Nodes are the gateways where encrypted Tor traffic hits the
>   Internet. This means an exit node can be abused to monitor Tor traffic
>   (after it leaves the onion network). It is in the design of the Tor
>   network that locating the source of that traffic through the network
>   should be difficult to determine. However if the exit traffic is
>   unencrypted and contains identifying information then an exit node can
>   be abused.

As with any other anonymity system, Tor isn't perfect. For a list of weaknesses I suggest checking out the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_%28anonymity_network%29#Weaknesses).

Assuming Tor works the way it is intended to, the answer to 1., 2., 3. is no.